# Advise clustering file system for storage for the array through the Fibre Channel

Tags: storage, virtualization, openstack

I deploy Openstack for private cloud. Faced a problem of a choice of file system for storage. That live migration between physical servers worked.

Configuration:
HP P2000 FC disk massif and four computing notes which are connected on through HBA FiberChanel to one general lun on storage.

Advise clustering file system without use of iscsi, fcoe... etc... Only FC. As VMFS from Vmware...

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you about OpenStack Object Storage aka Swift, you can use fibre channel across zones/regions/geo-cluster for data transfer.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are no good cluster filesystem alternatives to VMware VMFS on Linux. You may look at Oracle OCFS2, Red Hat GFS2, SGI CXFS and Symantec VxFS. All of them are dated. Newer generation of filesystems moved to distributed architecture over local drives (as compared to shared SAN) for scalability.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you need object file system Ceph, Lustre, NetApp object storage etc.
2. But you can create san cluster. I dont know MSA maybe not supported but 3Par have HP peer persistence.